# How to supply 12 volt DC to all the windows in a new house build

Tags: electrical, wiring, blinds

We are looking to provide 12v DC power to all the window headers in a new construction home for later use to power 12v DC blind motors. As all the walls are open for now we are just going to have wire running back to the central place in the mechanical room.

So I was wondering what the source of this power will be - some sort of transformer? Takes 120v AC and converts to 12v DC. But does something that will support 30+ outlets exist? They won't all be running at the sametime (in theory).

Also do we need a breaker box for DC. If there is an example article or something online that would be great too!

Cheers

Comment: Did somebody suggest this for you or is it just an idea you have? I'm asking because DC wiring depends a lot on the length of wire and the current being drawn. Most blinds controllers these days can use batteries. Are you trying to avoid that?

Comment: What make and model of blind controller are we talking about here?

Comment: Yes I am trying to avoid batteries to all the windows. I thought if building a house from scratch why not wire it properly. The house isn't huge. I have a room which is in the basement and central to the house. I think the longest wire won't be more than 30ft.

Comment: The blinds motor I was looking at is this one https://www.amazon.ca/Rollerhouse-Electric-Tubular-Hard-Wired-Switching/dp/B07F1MRKHW

Answer (score 4):

You just answered your own question, “how do I splice 30 connections” / “breaker box for DC”.  However only one breaker box/service panel/load center on the market is capable of supporting DC, and that is Square D’s “QO” type (the one with the 3/4” breakers; NOT the cheapie Homeline!)

The trick is **voltage drop**.  The much lower voltage is also much more sensitive to resistance loss through the wires. That forces you into larger wires.  The good news is, economics of scale make #12 or #14 wire intended for AC mains *barely more expensive* than the #18 or #22 one normally associates with low voltage DC.  There’s no substitute for figuring out your current draws and doing the load calculations based on your distance. This must be done.

Note that 24-volt systems are 4 times better for voltage drop. Crunch the numbers and you’ll see.  If it’s feasible to go 24V, consider it.

### A shame to only use it for blinds

12V or 24V DC systems can be an incredibly verstaile addition to a home, and can even allow it to weather long power outages with high functionality, much moreso if the house is smartly designed around that idea.

For instance, a variety of LED lighting is made for 12/24V, including the popular LED strips, which dim very effectively, and even permit RGB color.  Motion sensors are cheaper in 12/24V.

If you make this auxiliary lighting, you could have it during power outages by adding a battery to the system.  Many Internet modems/routers work on 12V, as do many TVs, and a typical Roku box or other smart-box attachment will also like 12V power.  So there you are watching Netflix in the power outage.

12/24V house-sized refrigerators aren’t worth buying, but you can run an inverter for the times the fridge needs to run.

The batteries need to be sized for the run-time you want to have, but them *with some solar panels to top them up* can be a lot cheaper than an installed generator system with changeover switch, yadayada.  Heck a modest battery system is cheaper than those hokey 10-circuit switches alone.

Or very small generator can be used simply to top up the batteries during period of low sun (or for that matter, your car’s alternator).

It could build out into quite a system if you wanted to.

Comment: Thanks for all your thoughts.

Yes I appreciate you can do a lot - at one point I was researching using PoE to power lights for the house. But the technology is really for buildings at the moment.

I'm not too concerned about power going out and having to manage without. We live in Vancouver, CA and don't really have power issues.

Larger wires shouldn't be a problem - what guage makes sense to minimise power loss. I guess we could switch to 24 volts - maybe the blind controller can somehow manage that?

But I'm still not clear where this 12/24 volts comes from? a transformer?

Answer (score 2):

Voltages as low as 12 V are generally not used to distribute power in houses because the losses in wiring increase as the voltage drops (for a given power), so you will waste energy and have poorly running motors if you used the same wire sizes you might use for distributing AC to the same places. You can compensate for this by increasing the wire size, but you will of course pay more for the metal in those wires. To figure out what wire size you would need for your wire runs, look up how to calculate **“voltage drop”** in wires of a given length and voltage.

Also, using separate 120V-12V power supplies at each window or group of windows provides overcurrent protection without the need for a separate breaker box, because nearly all modern power supplies will have an automatic overload shutoff and restart.

(If for some reason you want to avoid dealing with 120 V wiring at each window, another option is to distribute a higher “low” voltage such as 24 V or 48 V and use DC-DC converters at each motor. This gets you much lower losses.)

---

For your specific application, I would suggest **consulting installation guides by motorized blind manufacturers** to see how they handle distributing power to an entire house's windows. They surely have standard approaches such that you don't have to invent it out of parts.

---

That said, to partially address your further questions:

- High current DC power supplies do exist. I don't know where to find one best suited for a hardwired installation; form factors I am familiar with are ones intended for installation inside enclosures (with screw terminals to fit input and output wiring), and desktop units commonly used by amateur radio operators (who use 12V equipment that can be used on automotive or battery power systems).
- If you have a central power supply you can and should have overcurrent protection at your distribution. I've heard that some of the breaker boxes and breakers you'd use for 120V are rated for DC, but I do not personally have knowledge of the area; I'm sure [Harper's answer](/questions/196818/how-to-supply-12-volt-dc-to-all-the-windows-in-a-new-house-build#196826) addresses this better than I can.

Note that **when you're installing wiring in walls, electrical codes care about it even though it's low voltage.** A poor connection or undersized wire can overheat and start a fire regardless of the voltage. I am not knowledgeable about the exact requirements (I'm an electronics hobbyist who hasn't yet had the opportunity to own a house) so make sure you check what's allowed, and use parts that are listed for the purpose.